# `fromdate` and `todate` parameter in `/me` call

Tags: support, api-v2.2, documentation

What if we don't give the `fromdate` and/or `todate` parameters in a [/me](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me) call?

Will it give result of user of all times? It's not mentioned explicitly in documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you omit those parameters it will give you the expected result...
If a valid token is passed, then it will return the user ("There can be only one.") who obtained/approved that token.

For this route, **the `fromdate` and `todate` parameters filter on the `creation_date` property** of [the `user` object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user).

So, if the authorized user signed up for his/her account outside of the range specified by any `fromdate` and/or `todate` values, then no user will be returned at all.

For example, [user *amit jha*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5035500/amit-jha) joined Stack overflow on June 22, 2015.  If fetches from [`/me`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me) and... :

- Leaves `fromdate` and `todate` blank, he gets a valid result.
- Sets `fromdate` to `1472688000` (Sept 1st, 2016), he gets no result (no user object).
- Sets `fromdate` to `1409529600` (Sept 1st, 2014), he gets a valid result.

---

I can't imagine a legitimate use for this. The presence of these parameters for this route just adds clutter, and confusion, with no purpose.

And, ironically, `/me/*` routes that could benefit immensely from date parameters (like [/me/inbox](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-inbox)) don't have them!

Comment: Good point regarding [/me/inbox](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-inbox). I feel they didn't give this facility because, this isn't available in website also.